# Magento 2 API. Can not send 2 params

Tags: magento2, api, soap

all!
I'm implementing my custom API and want to send 2 parameters for my method.
Here is my code:

1. app/code/Openc/GCApi/etc/module.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Openc_GCApi" setup_version="1.0.0" />
   </config>
   ```
2. app/code/Openc/GCApi/etc/webapi.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../app/code/Magento/Webapi/etc/webapi.xsd">
   <route url="/V1/opencGCApiGcapiapiStock/update/:productId/:data" method="POST">
   <service class="Openc\GCApi\Api\GcapiapiStockInterface" method="update"/>
   <resources>
       <resource ref="anonymous"/>
   </resources>
   ```
3. app/code/Openc/GCApi/Api/GcapiapiStockInterface.php

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Openc\GCApi\Api;
   interface GcapiapiStockInterface
   {
       /**
        * Returns greeting message to user
        *
        * @param string $productId
        * @param string[] $data
        * @return bool
        */
        public function update($productId = NULL, $data);
    }
   ```
4. app/code/Openc/GCApi/Model/GcapiapiStock.php

   ```
    <?php
    namespace Openc\GCApi\Model;
    use Openc\GCApi\Api\GcapiapiStockInterface;
    class GcapiapiStock implements GcapiapiStockInterface
    {
         /**
          * Returns greeting message to user
          *
          * @param string $productId
          * @param string[] $data
          * @return bool
          */
          public function update($productId = NULL, $data)
          {
              $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
              $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
              $logger->addWriter($writer);
              $logger->info(print_r($productId, true));
              $logger->info(print_r($data, true));
              return false;
          }
     }
   ```
5. app/code/Openc/GCApi/etc/di.xml

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
           <preference for="Openc\GCApi\Api\GcapiapiStockInterface" type="Openc\GCApi\Model\GcapiapiStock"/>
    </config>
   ```
6. app/code/Openc/GCApi/registration.php

   ```
   <?php
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
         \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
         'Openc_GCApi',
          __DIR__
   );
   ```

But in my custom log file I'm getting empty array as second parameter:

```
2017-11-06T16:12:26+00:00 INFO (6): 1
2017-11-06T16:12:26+00:00 INFO (6): Array
 (
 )
```

Fragment of my test script:

```
$result = $request->opencGCApiGcapiapiStockV1Update(array('productId' => 1, 
'data' => array('qty' => 26, 'is_in_stock' => 1, 'manage_stock' =>1, 'use_config_manage_stock' => 1, 'use_config_backorders' => 1, 'backorders' => 1)));
```

Could you please tell what can be the problem?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like it's with how/what params are being passed to the API call.

(i.e. It seems like you are passing 1 Array as a param, instead of 2 separate params 1 of which is a string and the other being an array)

Change your API call from

```
$result = $request->opencGCApiGcapiapiStockV1Update(array(  'productId' => 1, 
                                                            'data' => array('qty' => 26, 'is_in_stock' => 1, 'manage_stock' =>1, 'use_config_manage_stock' => 1,     'use_config_backorders' => 1, 'backorders' => 1)
                                                        )
                                                    );
```

to

```
$result = $request->opencGCApiGcapiapiStockV1Update(
                            'productId' => 1, 
                            'data' => array('qty' => 26, 'is_in_stock' => 1, 'manage_stock' =>1, 'use_config_manage_stock' => 1, 'use_config_backorders' => 1, 'backorders' => 1)
                        );
```

Good Luck! :)

Comment: Sorry, you've made mistake.  I've tried this call $result = $request->opencGCApiGcapiapiStockV1Update(1, 
  array('qty' => 26, 'is_in_stock' => 1, 'manage_stock' =>1, 'use_config_manage_stock' => 1, 'use_config_backorders' => 1, 'backorders' => 1));
but it gives error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] Error cannot find parameter in .../apitest.php

Comment: Could you upload your (zipped) entire module on here, as I'd like to debug it on my localhost.

Comment: Sure, here is the repo https://github.com/helmsmantest/Openc_GCApi. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Guys, any updates?

Comment: Sorry about the delay ... I don't see your test/client in the git repo. Could you upload that as well and include info on how you're testing/triggering it?

Comment: Added the file apitest.php in the project root dir.